# Separate tenant notification feeds

Tags: getstream-io

We are considering getstream.io for a B2B multi-tenant SaaS application's notifications feed.
Obviously, it should not be possible for users of a tenant to view and follow notifications and users of other tenants, respectively. 
We need to take care of this separation in the backend anyway. But I wondered whether there is a smart way within getstream.io to support this.
Any thoughts/advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't. You could create different "apps" or "feed groups" but those are all manual things.

The best way is to check on your application level, before you send any `follow` API calls to Stream, like you already have multi-tenant checks before logging in, viewing content, exporting stuff, ...